# Python Convert Fraction Inside String to Integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I convert an input entered as a fraction (eg, "4/2") into an integer in python 3.5? I have tried using both of the following codes:

```
b = int(input("Please enter a value for b of the quadratic equation: "))
b = int(float(input("Please enter a value for b of the quadratic equation: ")))
```

Answer (score 20):

**Use [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/fractions.html).**

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> int(Fraction('4/2'))
2
```

Whatever you do, don't use `eval`.

Note that `int()` always rounds towards zero. Depending on the behaviour you want, you might want to check out `round()`, `math.floor()` or `math.ceil()`.

Comment: Well . . . that kind of beats my answer hands down, doesn't it?

Comment: Bad input will cause a `ValueError` exception that can be handled.

Answer (score 2):

With the standard library for regular expression `re`, you can test if the fraction is well formatted:

```
>>> import re
>>> fraction_pattern = re.compile(r"^(?P<num>[0-9]+)/(?P<den>[0-9]+)$")
```

and then:

```
>>> g = fraction_pattern.search('355/113')
>>> if g:
        f = float(g.group("num"))/float(g.group("den"))
>>> f
3.1415929203539825
```

But may not be the fastest nor the simplest solution compared to `fractions`...